# How to configure Flask app in Elastic Beanstalk to retain user uploaded image files using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask app has an image upload feature for example user profile photos and photos users upload for listings. The app is on Elastic Beanstalk.

I notice that whenever i run "eb deploy" command to redeploy after making a change it clears out the user uploaded image files and the links are broken. I am assuming this is because it restarts the server and gets rid of the files... I am assuming i need to define another location to store these files so that they are not cleared on redeployment ?

How can i create an S3 bucket and connect it with the flask app so that the user uploaded files are saved in the bucket and remain intact even after i restart the server/redeploy. If this isn't the correct method then what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming this is because it restarts the server and gets rid of the files.

That's correct. When you make a new deployment, EB will remove your current application from `/var/app/current` and replace with a new one.

> If this isn't the correct method then what is?

It is the correct way. For that to work you would need three things:

1. A bucket created for the images.
2. S3 permissions added to your [EB instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html) so that your application can write/read the images from the bucket.
3. Modified Flask app to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to interact with the bucket.

Depending on how you wish to make your images visible to your users, you can either make the images publicly readable, or limit their accessibility through [pre-signed S3 url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html).

**Update**

An IAM policy to read/write to a bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How would i configure the permissions for image uploads? Most of what I am seeing is for logs ?

Comment: @sn22 I updated the answer with example policy which could be added to the instance role.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!!